# SQL Creating SQL Server Agent Job with scheduler

Tags: sql-server, powershell, smo

I'm creating a SQL Server Agent Job with a scheduler.

Please see the script down below. The script works properly, but I have two issues:

1. I'd like to run the job not daily but monthly on first Monday of the month
2. I get no errors creating the job, but the job doesn't run, when I edit the scheduler, I get the error: "you must specify the target servers on which this multi server job will execute".

I just want to execute this job on the local machine, adding or deleting the line:

```
$SQLJob.AddSharedSchedule($SQLJobSchedule.ID)
```

makes no difference, I get the same error. Thanks for you help.

```
$ServerList = Get-Content F:\Logs\ListOfServers.txt

foreach ($srv in $ServerList)
{
    $SQLSvr = New-Object -TypeName  Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server($srv) 

    if ((Get-SQLAgentJob -ServerInstance $srv).Where{$_.Name -eq 
        'Delete_Users' -and $_.IsEnabled -eq $true})
    {
        Remove-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance $srv -Job 'Delete_Users' - 
        Confirm:$false
    }

    $SQLJob = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Agent.Job - 
    argumentlist $SQLSvr.JobServer, "Delete_Users"
    $SQLJob.Create()

    # step
    $SQLJobStep = New-Object -TypeName Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Agent.JobStep 
    -argumentlist $SQLJob, "Step1_Delete_Users"
    $SQLJobStep.Command = $Command
    $SQLJobStep.DatabaseName = "master"
    $SQLJobStep.Create()

    # schedule
    $SQLJobSchedule =  New-Object -TypeName 
    Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SMO.Agent.JobSchedule -argumentlist $SQLJob, 
    "Delete_Users_Scheduler" 
    $SQLJobSchedule.FrequencyTypes =  "Daily"
    $SQLJobSchedule.FrequencyInterval = 1
    $TimeSpan1 = New-TimeSpan -hours 15 -minutes 10
    $SQLJobSchedule.ActiveStartTimeofDay = $TimeSpan1 
    $SQLJobSchedule.ActiveStartDate = get-date
    $SQLJobSchedule.create()
    $SQLJob.AddSharedSchedule($SQLJobSchedule.ID)
    $SQLJob.Alter()
}
```

Comment: Consider adding calendar table.  This way the agent runs daily, and aborts if it  isNOT the first Monday of the month after a quick test.

Comment: I'll try that, but the main issue is the error with the "target server", even if correctly created, the job doesn't run.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why are you mixing DbaTools and SMO? Why not just do everything with DbaTools and `Set-DbaAgentSchedule`? Side note: the more modern way to create a new object in PS is `$SQLSvr = [Microsoft.SQLServer.Management.Smo.Server]::new($srv);`

Comment: $SQLSvr.JobServer looks very suspect to me. Wouldn't one pass the actual sql server object

Comment: @siggemannen - [the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.job.-ctor?view=sql-smo-160#microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-agent-job-ctor(microsoft-sqlserver-management-smo-agent-jobserver-system-string)) wants a JobServer object.

Comment: I'd try adding a call to `$SQLJob.ApplyToTargetServer('(local)')`. Which, FWIW, I cribbed from New-DbaAgentJob (which speaks to an earlier point @Charlieface made - why aren't you using that?).

Comment: @BenThul you're right, oops. But shouldn't it be ApplyToTargetServer($srv) since i'm guessing OP wants to create jobs on different servers than local

Comment: @siggemannen - I don't think so. The argument is in relation to the job server against which the command is being run. I took the original statement of problem as "I want to create this job on a plurality of independent servers" which means it's local to the job itself. Corroborating evidence is that if I script out an arbitrary job on my local instance, I see a call to `sp_add_jobserver` with an argument of '(local)' for the `@server_name` param.

Comment: @BenThul, that makes sense, i scripted some job myself and it went as local as well.

Comment: I solved it using dbatools using the 3 functions in a row:
New-DbaAgentJob -SqlInstance $srv -Job $JobName -OwnerLogin "sa" -EnableException
        New-DbaAgentJobStep -SqlInstance $srv -Job $JobName -StepName $JobStepName -Subsystem TransactSql -Command $Command -OnSuccessAction QuitWithSuccess -OnFailAction QuitWithFailure -EnableException
New-DbaAgentSchedule -SqlInstance $srv -Job $JobName -Schedule $JobScheduler -FrequencyType Weekly -FrequencyInterval Monday -StartTime 050000 -Force -EnableException

Comment: I am not particularly happy about it, as dbatools can sometimes be very verbose, but what can you do? The problem I couldn't solve was: target\local server. Assigning it as 'local' also didn't work.